# itertools.cycle(iterable) vs while True

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, python-itertools

I was recently asked to do this task (school) :

> Write a **loop** generator, which takes as parameter a finite iterable, and generates in infinite loop the iterable

So I did :

```
import itertools
def loop(l):
    for eleme‍‌​‍‌nt in itertools.cycle(l):
        yield element
```

and one of my classmate did :

```
def loop(l):
    while True:
​‍         for element in l:
            yield element
```

I'd like to know what are the main differences between the two and if there is a more "pythonic" way to write something simple as this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd like to know what are the main differences between the two ...

The main difference is that these code snippets are not entirely equivalent in behaviour.  Using `cycle`, you can accept and repeat an exhaustible iterator, whereas the `while` loop can not.

```
>>> def gen():
...     yield 1
...     yield 2
...     
>>> def loop_it(it):
...     for element in itertools.cycle(it):
...         yield element
...         
>>> g = loop_it(gen())
>>> next(g)
1
>>> next(g)
2
>>> next(g)
1
```

Contrast:

```
>>> def loop_while(it):
...     while True:
...         for element in it:
...             yield element
...             
>>> g = loop_while(gen())
>>> next(g)
1
>>> next(g)
2
>>> next(g)
# ... hangs forever
```

> ... and if there is a more "pythonic" way to write something simple as this

My recommendation is for the `while` loop, exactly as written.  If you are asked in a school task to *write* the generator, it will likely be frowned upon to use "one prepared earlier" from itertools. The `while` loop is also more Pythonic. An "itertoolsthonic" approach would instead be using the cycle directly, like this:

```
items = itertools.cycle(l)
# do something with `items`
```

There is no point to write the extra scaffolding of a generator function and for loop yielding from an `itertools.cycle` - since the cycle is already an iterator, you would just use it directly.

Comment: Technically, `gen` (or even more technically, its return value) is an *iterator*, not an *iterable*.

Comment: @chepner  I would say the return value of a generator function is *both* an iterator and an iterable. I would go so far as to say that *every* iterator is an iterable.

Comment: Well, there is no problem with using some libs, we are in the last year but we didn't have a python module yet. So using libs is not an issue. However our teacher do a lot of code golfing :)

Answer (score 3):

You're right, `itertools.cycle` isn't of great interest here over the classical `while True` loop.

On the other hand, it's of great help in infinite *generator comprehensions*, where you cannot create an infinite loop because it only allows `for`, tests and function calls. Example to generate squared value of a list indefinitely:

```
generator = (x*x for x in itertools.cycle(l))
```

Of course you could always shorten your current code with:

```
def loop(l):
    yield from itertools.cycle(l)
```

or even:

```
loop = itertools.cycle
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, the purpose of `itertools.cycle` is that you wouldn't have to write it yourself at all :)

The most pythonic way would be to simply write `loop = itertools.cycle`.

If you truly need to write it as a generator for your school assignment, the second form would probably perform faster, because the first form basically does the same but also has additional overhead from re-yielding the values from `cycle` in your generator.